# Is there a better way to get dict values in a dict list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like this:

```
[{'enter_time': '2021-03-01 07:15:16', 'leave_time': '2021-03-01 07:16:06'}, {'enter_time': '2021-03-02 08:15:16', 'leave_time': '2021-03-02 08:16:06'}]
```

As you can see, every item in the list is a dict.
Now, I wanna get a new list consisting of all `enter_time` and `leave_time`.
I should get a new list like this:

```
>>> new_list
>>> ['2021-03-01 07:15:16', '2021-03-01 07:16:06', '2021-03-02 08:15:16', '2021-03-02 08:16:06']
```

I have tried in a awkward way:

```
datetime_str_list = [{'enter_time': '2021-03-01 07:15:16', 'leave_time': '2021-03-01 07:16:06'}, {'enter_time': '2021-03-02 08:15:16', 'leave_time': '2021-03-02 08:16:06'}]
new_list = []
for item in datetime_str_list:
    for dict_value in item.values():
        new_list.append(dict_value)
print('new_list', new_list)
```

I have no idea how to implement this in a elegant way. Looking forward to your solutions.

Comment: A better way? Have you already tried something?

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
times = [{'enter_time': '2021-03-01 07:15:16', 'leave_time': '2021-03-01 07:16:06'}, 
        {'enter_time': '2021-03-02 08:15:16', 'leave_time': '2021-03-02 08:16:06'}]
```

## Explicit approach

I start by creating a list to hold the results (`new_times`).
For each item in the original list called `times`, we extract the values associated with each of the two keys: `enter_time` and `leave_time`.

We can reference each of these using the syntax `item['enter_time']` OR `item['leave_time']`.

The `.extend()` method of the Python list object allows us to extend a list by adding multiple items to the end of the list (as compared to the `.append() method which only adds one item at a time).

```
new_times = list()
for item in times:
    new_times.extend([item['enter_time'], item['leave_time']])
```

With that, `new_times` should yield:

```
['2021-03-01 07:15:16',
 '2021-03-01 07:16:06',
 '2021-03-02 08:15:16',
 '2021-03-02 08:16:06']
```

## More concise approach (and probably more Pythonic approach)

If there is no benefit to explicitly referencing the individual elements of item, we can simply reference them all by calling for the `.values` associated with each `item` dictionary.

```
new_times = list()
for item in times:
     new_times.extend(item.values())
```

## Nested List Comprehension approach:

There is the ability to do this with nested comprehensions, but that may come at the cost of readability.

```
new_times_lc = [value for subdict in times for value in subdict.values()]
```

Basically, this is equivalent to a nested `for` loop.

Comment: Wow, it's more concise and efficient I think. BTW, Is there a approach using like one-line list comprehension.

Comment: @Gorgine I added a bit to show how this can be done with a single nested List Comprehension.

Comment: Thx a lot. I prefer the second one. `extend` did the trick. I think I should use it more often in right occasions.

Answer (score 2):

for a list comprehension approach:

```
new_list = [list(d.values()) for d in old_list]
flat_list = [i for sublist in new_list for i in sublist]
```

This will assign all values in the original dictionaries into a list of lists, and then flatten that list into a 1D list of all the values

Answer (score 1):

Using the map function:

```
from itertools import chain

times = [{'enter_time': '2021-03-01 07:15:16', 'leave_time': '2021-03-01 07:16:06'}, {'enter_time': '2021-03-02 08:15:16', 'leave_time': '2021-03-02 08:16:06'}]

new_times = list(chain(*list(map(lambda x: list(x.values()), times))))
```

This gets the values from each dictionary and unpacks them, similarly to the list comprehensions.

Comment: Great! `itertools.chain` here flattened 2D list into 1D one, am I right?

Comment: @Gorgine Effectively yes. The map function returns a list of two lists in this case, the * character unpacks the two smaller lists from the large list, and then the two smaller lists are combined with the chain function